# need to do a query when button is pressed php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, button

I want to so when a button is pressed on my page it runs a query in the database

**View**

```
<form method="POST" action="evcccontroller/query">
        <input type="submit" name="nw_update" value="NW_Update"/>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function query()
{
    // load the index view
    $this->load->view('querycheck');
}
```

**querycheck.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['nw_update']))
{
    echo("You clicked button one!");
    //and then execute a sql query here
}
else 
{
    echo" dhur";
}
```

An Error Was Encountered

> The action you have requested is not allowed.

Comment: try action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/evcccontroller/query">

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your `action` attr of form try like

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/evcccontroller/query">
                            <input type="submit" name="nw_update" value="NW_Update"/>
                        </form>
```

Comment: what is the echo base_url used for?? 
i get the error 
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 0):

add base url to form action

```
action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/evcccontroller/query"
```

Comment: <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/evcccontroller/query">
                                <input type="submit" name="nw_update" value="NW_Update"/>
                            </form>

i have done that but still get 
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found
But I can get straight to the url http://localhost/evcc/evcccontroller/query and it works, it only dosen't work when i go though the button

Comment: Please send your site url, where its running, inspact and check whether your base url is working fine.

Comment: Do you remove index.php from your site. if so, than try these config details in your confing file
`$config['base_url'] = "/evcc/";`
`$config['index_page'] = '';`

if index.php is not removed from url than create .htaccess file in evcc directory and use following htaccess code
`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /evcc/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]`

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciate it.
but  still getting the error.
i can go to the 
http://localhost/evcc/evcccontroller/query
and it loads fine

Comment: and i changed the setting and it didn't do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

code is looking fine. I think the form action url is wrong. try this:

```php
<form method="POST" action="<?=base_url('index.php/evcccontroller/query')?>">
    <input type="submit" name="nw_update" value="NW_Update"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('evcccontroller/query')?>">
     <input type="submit" name="nw_update" value="NW_Update"/>
</form>
```